# Why do I get a Spring Boot (Java) error Access-Control-Allow-Origin can't be *, while it's sending the right header?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, tomcat10

I have a simple web app containing a Angular front-end and a Spring Boot API using Spring security JWT authentication (version 3.0.5) deployed in Tomcat 10. The Web server and APP/DB server are separate. I will censor out the domain for privacy reasons, and will replace it with example.com.

I have Cors configured like this:

```
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://goods.example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Filename"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

My Spring Security config is the following:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
//                .requiresChannel()
//                .anyRequest()
//                .requiresSecure()
//                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests( authCustomizer -> authCustomizer
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/test").permitAll()
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .headers()
                .xssProtection()
                .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self' data: blob:;");

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

As you can see I'm running the app on http for now.

When I call my authentication endpoint with valid credentials it shows the the following headers:

```http
HTTP/1.1 403 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://goods.example.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Jwt-Token, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Filename
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 03 May 2023 09:11:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive
```

Now here is the problem. In my logs I get the following error: `c.o.g.exception.DefaultExceptionHandler  : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.`

In my view I am listing the allowed origins explicitly in my cors configuration, but for some reason it is not working...

What I tried:

- I tried changing the Collections.singletonList() to Arrays.asList()
- Removing XSS and CSP
- Changing the Class annotation Order to: `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`
- Check whether there's any cors rules active in Tomcat (I can't find any)
- Use setAllowedOriginPatterns OR addAllowedOriginPattern instead of setAllowOrigins
- Add the @Bean annotation to my CorsConfigurationSource

These were the fixes I found in other threads/could think of on my own.

Just to specify, I do not get an error in the browser, just in Java/Tomcat. Probably because spring boot does give the correct header back...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nothing in the code that you've posted explain an error with such a message. Either you're not telling us everything, or the message is inaccurate.

Comment: These are the only things I would think are related to the error I'm getting. Could you give me some guidance on extra information that's needed for my message to be more complete? Quite new to all this, sorry!

Comment: There must be a call to `allowedOrigins("*")` somewhere. Find it and you'll be one step closer to fixing your CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I didn't configure the CORS properly. This is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(request -> {
            CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
            cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
            cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
            cors.setExposedHeaders(List.of(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE));
            return cors;
        }))
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        ...
```

This will allow any origin to be served. Also for any method.